# How can I get a quadratic equation from data without graphing?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to solve a simple question of "find x at y". I have two data that I can fit into an equation, but I want to be able to find the Y at X without having to graph it and analytically finding a trendline.

For example:

```
X   Y
100 20
200 30
300 50
400 80
500 130
    
Find Y at 350
```

If this was linear it'd be simple since you could find the slope & intercept through excel, but i'm not sure if you can do the same for quadratic. How can I go about tackling this?

Comment: all the different types are discussed [HERE](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2019/01/16/excel-trendline-types-equations-formulas/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX(LINEST(B2:B6,A2:A6^{1,2}),1)  the coefficient of the squared term
```

In **C2** enter:

```
=INDEX(LINEST(B2:B6,A2:A6^{1,2}),1,2)  the coefficient of the linear term
```

In **C3** enter:

```
=INDEX(LINEST(B2:B6,A2:A6^{1,2}),1,3)  the constant term.
```

Put 350 in **A7** and in **D7** enter:

```
=$C$1*A7^2+$C$2*A7+$C$3
```

[image]

Note:

**D2** through **D6** result from **D7** being copied **upward**.

**EDIT#1 based on Scott Craner's suggestion:**

This is for **EXCEL 365**.  Say we want to get to a formula resembling:

A*z<sup>2</sup> + B*z + C

where *z* is the value in **A7**.  In **D7** enter:

```
=LET(z,A7,x,$A$2:$A$6,y,$B$2:$B$6,ln,LINEST(y,x^{1,2}),A,INDEX(ln,1),B,INDEX(ln,1,2),C,INDEX(ln,1,3),A*z^2 + B*z + C)
```

This formula does not require the quadratic coefficients to be stored in **C1** through **C3**.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Very nice..................I will update the answer..............

Comment: @ScottCraner  .........Done.....................

Comment: Thank you! This is what I need. I just want to understand this a little bit, i think my confusion might just be from my lacking ability in statistics. when you do A2:A6^{1,2}, does this just square the x value since LINEST is usually for linear regression?